# How to sum all averages in SQL by client id by adding subquery?

Tags: sql, sum, subquery, average

I wrote query that calculate average by month in SQL but now I would like to also add sum all averages by client_id. I tried to add subquery but it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
SELECT to_char(cd.date, 'YYYYMM') AS date_format_m,
       cd.client_id,
       csd.owner_email,
       AVG(mrr)
FROM client_data AS cd
LEFT JOIN client_static_data AS csd ON cd.client_id = csd.client_id
WHERE cd.date > '2021-09-01' and mrr > 0
GROUP by date_format_m, cd.client_id, csd.owner_email
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just use `SUM()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(cd.date, 'YYYYMM') AS date_format_m,
    cd.client_id,
    csd.owner_email,
    AVG(mrr),
    SUM(AVG(mrr)) OVER (PARTITION BY cd.client_id) mrr_avg_sum
FROM client_data AS cd
LEFT JOIN client_static_data AS csd ON cd.client_id = csd.client_id
WHERE cd.date > '2021-09-01' AND mrr > 0
GROUP by date_format_m, cd.client_id, csd.owner_email;
```

If the above is not what you want, and instead you want just one record for each owner email and date, then just subquery what you currently have:

```sql
SELECT
    date_format_m,
    owner_email,
    SUM(mrr_avg) AS mrr_avg_sum        
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(cd.date, 'YYYYMM') AS date_format_m,
        cd.client_id,
        csd.owner_email,
        AVG(mrr) AS mrr_avg
    FROM client_data AS cd
    LEFT JOIN client_static_data AS csd ON cd.client_id = csd.client_id
    WHERE cd.date > '2021-09-01' AND mrr > 0
    GROUP by date_format_m, cd.client_id, csd.owner_email
) t
GROUP BY date_format_m, owner_email;
```